# Python 3.6 - enumerate files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to loop a series of jpg files in a folder. I found example code of that:

```
for n, image_file in enumerate(os.scandir(image_folder)):
```

which will loop through the image files in `image_folder`. However, it seems like it is not following any sequence. I have my files name like `000001.jpg`, `000002.jpg`, `000003.jpg`,... and so on. But when the code run, it did not follow the sequence:

```
000213.jpg
000012.jpg
000672.jpg
....
```

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir)? If you did, you would know the answer. As for the remedy, have the files sorted before enumerating them.

Comment: ... and, because _you want_ `file_9.jpg` to come before `file_10.jpg`, have a look at the [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) module

Answer (score 4):

Here's the relevant bit on [os.scandir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir):

> os.**scandir**​*(path='.')*
>
> Return an iterator of `os.DirEntry` objects
>   corresponding to the entries in the directory given by *path*. The
>   entries are yielded in **arbitrary order**, and the special entries `'.'`
>   and `'..'` are not included.

You should not expect it to be in any particular order.  The same goes for [`listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) if you were considering this as an alternative.

If you strictly need them to be in order, consider sorting them first:

```
scanned = sorted([f for f in os.scandir(image_folder)], key=lambda f: f.name)
for n, image_file in enumerate(scanned):

# ... rest of your code
```

Comment: I added `scanned = sorted([f for f in os.scandir(image_folder)])` and getting error:`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'posix.DirEntry' and 'posix.DirEntry'`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `glob`:

> The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern
>   according to the rules used by the Unix shell, although results are
>   returned in arbitrary order. No tilde expansion is done, but *, ?, and
>   character ranges expressed with [] will be correctly matched.

You will need this if you handle more complex file structures so starting with glob isnt that bad. For your case you also can use `os.scandir()` as mentioned above.

Reference: [glob module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#module-glob)

```
import glob
files = sorted(glob.glob(r"C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\stack\img\*.jpg"))
for key, myfile in enumerate(files):
    print(key, myfile)
```

*notice even if there other files like `.txt` they wont be in your `list`*

Output:

```
C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\stack>python c:/Users/Fabian/Desktop/stack/img.py
0 C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\stack\img\img0001.jpg
1 C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\stack\img\img0002.jpg
2 C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\stack\img\img0003.jpg
....
```